# Tikz opacity problem with rectangle split

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw the red line under the gray TEXT box? The white background should be transparent.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzstyle{style}=[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split part fill={white, gray}, rectangle split horizontal=false, draw=black, thick]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[style, minimum size=5cm](A) {
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[style, minimum size=2cm](B) {
          123456789123456789
          \nodepart{two}TEXT};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \nodepart{two}TEXT
  };
  \draw[-, red, thick](A.north west) -- (A.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding opacity=<between 0 and 1>, say 0.3, into the draw options at the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it like this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}

\tikzstyle{style}=[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split part fill={white, gray}, rectangle split horizontal=false, draw=black, thick]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[style, minimum size=5cm](A) {
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[style, minimum size=2cm](B) {
          123456789123456789
          \nodepart{two}TEXT};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \nodepart{two}TEXT
  };
  \draw[-, red, thick]($(A.south west) + (0,-.5ex)$) -- ($(A.south east) + (0,-.5ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}

\tikzset{
style/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split part fill={white, gray}, rectangle split horizontal=false, draw=black, thick}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[style, minimum size=5cm](A) {
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[style, minimum size=2cm](B) {
          123456789123456789
          \nodepart{two}TEXT};
          \draw[-, red, thick]($(B.south west) + (0,-.5ex)$) -- ($(B.south east) + (0,-.5ex)$);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \nodepart{two}TEXT
  };
  \draw[-, red, thick]($(A.south west) + (0,-.5ex)$) -- ($(A.south east) + (0,-.5ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `tikzpicture` inside `tikzpicture` can be troublesome. Also instead of `tikzstyle`, use `tikzset` (as in the latter code) as the former is deprecated.

Or this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\tikzset{
style/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split part fill={none, gray}, rectangle split horizontal=false, draw=black, thick}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[style, minimum size=5cm,opacity=1](A) {
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[style, minimum size=2cm](B) {
          123456789123456789
          \nodepart{two}TEXT};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \nodepart{two}TEXT
  };
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw[-, red, thick,](A.north west) -- (A.south east);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, now I am confused. :-)

Comment: Thx. It is not really what I want but your examples put me on the right track... :) "rectangle split part fill={none, gray}" together with "pgfonlayer" solved my problem.

Comment: @user4811 Glad it helped. You meant *behind* not under :-). I have updated the answer for the record.